# SVG size in comparison to parent container. Why doesn't 100% min-height fill parent?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG (the red rectangle in the screenshot)in a child DIV element, which is inside parent DIV element (the green rectangle).

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;  
  height: 400px; 
  width: 270px;
}

.child {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1"  viewPort="550 0 600 430.95" viewBox="246 0 600 430.95" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" >
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
</svg>

 </div>
</div>
```

I want to the SVG to scale to the same size as the parent DIV, so I've used the min-height attribute, which I've set to 100%. For some reason the SVG in the child DIV doesn't scale to the size of the parent DIV, and is much smaller. I am confused why this is the case, and would have thought it would have scaled to the same size. Does anyone know why it doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `min-width` and `min-height` don't work in this situation, just use `width` and `height` instead.
2. If you don't specify a `height` for your SVG, the browser will calculate one for you based on the `width` and the aspect ratio of the `viewBox`.  The `width` defaults to `"100%"`, so the width will be 100% of the parent width (270px) and the height will be:

   ```
   270 * 430.95 / 600 ~= 194px
   ```
3. Setting the height of the SVG to `"100%"` will make the SVG the same height as `div.child`, but the `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` will mean that the SVG contents will be centred in the `div`.

   ```css
   .parent {
     position: relative;
     background: green;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     display: inline-block;
     overflow: hidden;  
     height: 400px; 
     width: 270px;
   }

   .child {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="parent">
       <div class="child">

   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1"  viewBox="246 0 600 430.95" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="100%" height="100%">
   <rect width="846" height="100%" fill="red" />
   </svg>

    </div>
   </div>
   ```

   If you want the SVG to ignore the aspect ratio, and stretch to the height of the `div`, then set `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;  
  height: 400px; 
  width: 270px;
}

.child {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1"  viewBox="246 0 600 430.95" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%">
<rect width="846" height="100%" fill="red" />
</svg>

 </div>
</div>
```

PS. there is no such SVG attribute as `viewPort`.

Comment: Hello thanks for the response! I do want the aspect of the SVG preserved. However, in your example the aspect ratio of the SVG has changed even though you've used preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" . When I look at the SVG on it's own, it a rectangle with the long sides on the vertical axis, but in your 1st snippet the rectangle is the other way around with the long sides on the X axis. Also, where does the the '846' value come from in the SVG you've used in your first snippet? I want the whole SVG viewbox to be displayed in red so I chose 100% height and width for the red rectangle.

Comment: If you want the aspect ratio preserved, then you can't fill a tall narrow div with a short wide SVG without some of the SVG being cut off. If you are okay with that, then use `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`.  The 846 comes from `viewBox.x + viewBox.width = (246 + 600)`.